# Button click not firing in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have user control deriving from BaseUserControl class and Now I need to add button in UserControl file(ascx)

I have added following code snippet in ascx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"  runat="server"  Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

Below is the code sample of ascx.cs file

```
public partial class MyContol : BaseUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
    // code to execute after button is clicked
    }
 }
```

But here the button event is not triggering and during debug I am able to see its hitting Page_Load event, please help me to resolve on this.

Regards

Anand

Comment: can you post more of your ascx markup?

Comment: Hi,Please find the mark up.public partial class MyControl: BaseUserControl
    { protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }}protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {}}   <%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this type of thing many times. Try the following.

1. Remove the button from the ASCX side of the page.
2. Remove the C# btn submit method.
3. Save the page.
4. Now go into design view...
5. Add the button back, assign the name in design view.
6. In Design View double click on the button so that it created the C# method for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried the approach what you have suggested but it didn't work out :(